# How Do I Disable A Div From Loading with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is make my website show 10 posts, then ask the user if he/she wants to load the "next page." What I want this "next page" button to do is load the content when the user clicks it.

The reason I want the div to just not load completely at all is for website speed. If my website hits let's say 100 posts, even if I just use a simple `.hide();` function or something, then the website's still going to take it's time trying to load the 90 posts the website is hiding.

And yes I do realize if I'm worried about page performance I could just make new pages every time I reach 10 posts but that seems like it'd take a lot of time and be very confusing because it wouldn't work in order or something would be wrong with it.

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but depending on where you are pulling these posts from, they should have an api that would allow you to only pull in x amount of posts at once, then when you click the load more it will load more posts. I hear AJAX is good for this sort of thing as well but I don't have much experience with it, however if you google AJAX load more im sure youll get some results that might point you in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If it is in the HTML document then it will be sent to the browser. It will be too late to stop it from loading at that point.

The only way to stop the div content from loading is to not have the div in the document in the first place, and then fetch more data from the server (which you would typically do with a link to the next page optionally with JavaScript progressively enhancing things to load the extra data with Ajax instead).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is an XHR or Ajax request to get the next 10 posts, it is much better to do it this way rather than hiding them and activating them as needed, because even if you hide it the browser still had to download the content.

You should start by displaying just a few posts, and then load more as needed using XHR/Ajax.

jQuery provides some simple `.ajax` functions that should help you with retrieving the data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is your best bet.

For your needs you could do this two ways:

1. Make AJAX load more posts as soon as the user clicks the button.
2. As soon as your page loads (JQ ready function) you could fire an AJAX call to get 10 more posts and either print them in a DOM hidden element OR save them in some variable for later use. After you recover the posts succesfully (AJAX .success()) you could call the AJAX function again and run it again and make it repeat this process until it caches say... 100 posts in a variable or prints it in your DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an [ajax call](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/) every time the user clicks the button and append the result to the last div on your page using jquery

```
$( ".container" ).append( $( "div" ) );
```

If you want to create a page which will not load all the content at once and not have the user click a button, you can use lazyloading.

It was developed for loading of images, but it can be used for loading of div's too. See [Layz Loading for Div](https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any/issues/9)

This works both when the user scrolls down and if they navigate to another page and then go back, it will only load part of the page that is visible. Meaning, if they are at the bottom, and they scroll up, it will reload the div's above.